Get state of build policies in Azure DevOps Pull request
I am trying to enhance my (C#) utility that can currently already Create a pull request using the GitHttpClient. I can query the PR and update it using UpdatePullRequestAsync.
What i am currently struggling with is to find a way to get the state of the build(s) that are linked to the PR. I explored the dotnet samples, but these are fairly limited: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/blob/main/ClientLibrary/Samples/Git/PullRequestIterationStatusesSample.cs
The statuses are empty.
What would be the correct/best way to get the build status for a pull request using the client libraries?
In the end, i want to (force) complete my pull request if all the linked builds are successful. Which if im correct should be done like this:
// now complete the PR
var updatedPr = new GitPullRequest()
{
    Status = PullRequestStatus.Completed,
    CompletionOptions = new GitPullRequestCompletionOptions() { SquashMerge = true, DeleteSourceBranch = true, BypassPolicy = true }

};

var prStatus = gitClient.UpdatePullRequestAsync(updatedPr, repoId, pullRequestId).Result;
               

How can help me point to the right way getting this information?

Hi @Nico, Good day. Have you got a chance to check my answer below to use GetPullRequestStatusesAsync to get the statuses of the validation build iterations? Hope your query in this post can be resolved. Thx.

As far as I have tested, you may try and use GetPullRequestStatusesAsync to get the PR iteration statuses.
Here is my code snippet for your reference.
// Get the pull request statuses
var statuses = gitClient.GetPullRequestStatusesAsync(projectName, repoName, pullRequestId).Result;

// Serialize the object to JSON
string statusesJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(statuses, Formatting.Indented);

// Print the JSON
Console.WriteLine("============ Satuses ============");
Console.WriteLine(statusesJson);



Thanks for the details, i believe i had tried this but it returned 0 at that point. I will test it again soon once priorities allow me.

Sure and good luck with the works to go.

If i try this using the REST Api as a quick test, _apis/git/repositories/8d3c48e2-1273-404b-b918-cd4d9a0a37b2/pullRequests/90193/statuses?api-version=7.1 is returning count 0, while testing on a Pull Request that has a build policy that has not run yet.
This is on Azure DevOps Server 2022 Update 1

That's wield. You may post the API issue in Developer Community to engage insights from the product team.
